# Difference between Cantonese /gw/ and Mandarin /gu/?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, cross-linguistic, chinese

As a native speaker of both languages, Cantonese /gw/ like in 過gwo3 and Mandarin /gu/ like in 过guo4 sounds the same, but I've checked that the Cantonese one is [kʷɔː] while the Mandarin one is [kwo], is there really a difference?

Comment: What is your basis for claiming that one has [kw] and the other has [kʷ]? E.g. "This book on Cantonese says [kʷ], that book on Mandarin says [kw]". This is almost certainly an indiosyncratic different in author theories, and is not about the languages.

Comment: The only difference which might be worth noting is that HK Cantonese often delabialises [kʷɔ] to [kɔ] in many environments.

Comment: @jogloran The equivalent is true of Mandarin (before /o/), though.

Comment: Is it? I've heard of 波, 破 being delabialised in Southern Mandarin, but never heard of 過 being delabialised.

Comment: @jogloran Well, there’s nothing to contrast with phonemically (no _*go_), so there’s a lot of wiggle room – but in my experience, it’s perfectly common to pronounce 过 as something more like [ko͡ɔ˥˩] or perhaps [k͗o͡ɔ˥˩] than actual [kwo͡ɔ˥˩]. For dentals and retroflexes, the process is more complete: 脱 多 说 are generally [tʰo͡ɔ˥ to͡ɔ˥ ʂo͡ɔ˥], not [tʍo͡ɔ˥ two͡ɔ˥ ʂwo͡ɔ˥].

Comment: @user6726 The sources are wikipedia pages, I then realized that might not be very reliable.

Comment: Mandarin Chinese has two alternative phonological analyses, the one where <gu> is /kw/ and the other where it is /kʷ/. See _The Phonology of Standard Chinese_, 2nd ed., 2007, Oxford, by San Duanmu.

Comment: @YellowSky Thanks for the information!

Comment: In Chinese phonology, the part between the initial consonant (声母) and the main vowel (韵腹) is called 介音. Some examples in Mandarin are `u` in 过 (guo) and `i` in 介 (jie). Cantonese has lost all of its 介音 except the w in gw and kw. So it's more convenient to analysis this w as just a part of the initial consonant instead of a 介音.

Comment: @alephalpha Oh I was not aware of this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an *extremely narrow* transcription:

- [kʷ] is a single sound, a type of [k] with rounded lips. The lips are rounded at the same time as the occlusion starts, and they're unrounded as soon as the occlusion ends (plosive burst).
- [kw] is a sequence of two sounds. First you get a [k], with unrounded lips; you'll get the occlusion and the burst. *Then* you get the [w], where the lips are rounded and the tongue gets close to the velum without touching it, as typical for approximants.

In practice... well. Speech does not segment so neatly. More often than not, you'll hear speakers using [kʷ], [kʷw] and [kw] interchangeably, sometimes even for the same word in different utterances. So when you're transcribing a language, there's a lot of room to transcribe all those sounds as [kʷ] or [kw].

Often the decision between one or another will be personal, and up to the author. Sometimes however you'll get people transcribing it as [kʷ] because, for the sake of phonotactics, it behaves like a single unit; while [kw] would behave as two units.

Sorry if this does not directly answer your question, as I don't speak either language. But hope that it helps anyway.

Comment: You did answer my question, thank you. ^^